triangle free cubic graphs
Is there any classification of cubic triangle-free graphs? Which structural properties of cubic triangle-free graphs are known? How about their eigenvalues or any other useful properties?

The Petersen graph is cubic and triangle-free, and it's a counterexample to just about every statement in Graph Theory, so I'm going to guess that the class is too broad for there to be any useful common properties.
